# Arduino MQTT publish not working

Tags: arduino, mqtt, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I have a problem with my Arduino. I am trying to learn MQTT, but it doesn't work with my code. I am using shiftr.io to view the MQTT actions. A publish via the Mac terminal comes true, but I don't see any action from the Arduino.

I am using the WiFi shield on top off an Arduino Uno.

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <MQTTClient.h>

const char ssid[] = "  /* Filed in in the code */ ";
const char pass[] = "  /* Filed in in the code */ ";

WiFiClient net;
MQTTClient client;

unsigned long lastMillis = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

  // Note: Local domain names (e.g. "Computer.local" on OSX) are not supported by Arduino.
  // You need to set the IP address directly.
  client.begin("broker.shiftr.io", net);
  client.onMessage(messageReceived);

  connect();
}

void connect() {
  Serial.print("checking wifi...");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(1000);
  }

  Serial.print("\nconnecting...");
  while (!client.connect("arduino", "try", "try")) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(1000);
  }

  Serial.println("\nconnected!");

  client.subscribe("/hello");
  // client.unsubscribe("/hello");
}

void loop() {
  client.loop();

  if (!client.connected()) {
    connect();
    Serial.print("not");
  }

  // publish a message roughly every second.
  if (millis() - lastMillis > 1000) {
    lastMillis = millis();
    client.publish("/hello", "world");
  }
}

void messageReceived(String &topic, String &payload) {
  Serial.println("incoming: " + topic + " - " + payload);
}
```

What I find strange is that the second include is differently colored.
Look at this screenshot:

[image]

I don't know what I am doing wrong. If you could help me that would be nice.

Comment: At the moment this is basically a "This code doens't work" type question with no error messages or indication what you've already tried to debug the problem. These types of question get closed as off topic. Update the question with any error message output and details of what you've tried e.g. are you sure that the code is connecting to the broker, have you tried a local broker?

Comment: The biggest part of my question is, is it normal that include isn't orange on line 2 like on the first line. Or is the libary not there or something.

Comment: It's been a while since I did any Arduino programming, but assuming there are no issues when you compile and deploy it shouldn't matter (it's probably just a built in header vs external one). But we need to see the compile errors if they are there.

Comment: No, there are no compile errors.

Comment: Side issue topics should as a rule not start with a leading `/`